# text to columns in sas

Tags: variables, sas

I want to process a comma-separated list of values in a variable (e.g., Q8) and create corresponding response variables (Q8_1, Q8_2, ..., Q8_17). For each value in the list, I want to set the corresponding response variable to 1 if there is a value. If the value is missing, the corresponding response variable should remain blank. Here is an example of what the variable initially looks like:

Q8

11

.

.

.

15,17

.

11,12,13,14,15

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

11

I tried something like this, but it's not accounting correctly for values 10+. any suggestions? I am not married to this code, so if someone has a completely different one, I am okay with that.

```
data numeric2;
set numeric;
run;
%macro initial2(var, num);
data numeric2;
format &var._1 - &var._&num 8.;
set numeric2;
run;
%mend;
%macro pop_var(var, num);
data numeric2;
set numeric2;
if index(&var, "&num")>0 then &var._&num = 1;
run;
%mend pop_var;

%macro run_pop(var2, num2);
%initial2(&var2, &num2);
%do i = 1 %to &num2;
%pop_var(&var2, &i);
%end;
%mend;

%run_pop(Q8, 17);`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the new variables to have 0 or 1 as the value then loop over the set of possible values (instead of looping over the set of existing values).

So if you have data like this:

```
data have;
  input Q8 $20.;
cards;
11
.
5,7
2,4,5,10,11
;
```

And the largest possible integer in the list is 11 then the code would look like this:

```
data want;
  set have;
  array q8_ q8_01 - q8_11;
  do index=1 to dim(q8_);
    q8_[index]=0<indexw(q8,cats(index),', ') ;
  end;
  drop index;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs Q8           q8_01  q8_02  q8_03  q8_04  q8_05  q8_06  q8_07  q8_08  q8_09  q8_10 q8_11

 1  11             0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     1
 2                 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     0
 3  5,7            0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0     0
 4  2,4,5,10,11    0      1      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This macro below will create a series of variables that is a 1 if it's in the list and 0 if it's not in the list. For example:

```
11 --> Q8_11 = 1
12 --> Q8_12 = 1
```

The way the below macro works is by first looping through all comma-separated values and finding the maximum value. This will let you create a dynamically-sized array. From there, we do a data step where we create an array which is exactly the size needed. We loop through each value in the comma-separated list and set its corresponding array variable to 1.

All you need is:

1. Your input dataset name
2. Your output dataset name
3. Your variable name

```
    %macro create_vars(data=, out=, var=);
    
        /* Dynamically identify the max value in the data */
        data _null_;
            set have end=eof;
            where NOT missing(&var);

            retain max_value 1;
    
            do i = 1 to countw(&var);
                value = input(scan(&var, i), 8.);
    
                if(value > max_value) then max_value = value;
            end;
        
            if(eof) then call symputx('max_value', max_value);
        run;
    
        data &out;
            set &data;
            array &var._[&max_value];
    
            do i = 1 to countw(&var);
                j = input(scan(&var, i), 8.);
                &var._[j] = 1;
            end;
    
            drop i j;
        run;
    %mend;

    %create_vars(data=have, out=want, var=Q8);
```

[image]